# Application Insights analytics - Select first value per category

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics, aiql

I want do an equivalent of the following SQL query -

(roughly)

```
SELECT 
    Name,
    application_Version
    Rank() OVER (PARTITION BY application_Version ORDER BY CountOfEventNamePerVersion)
FROM
    customEvents
```

Assuming I get the `CountOfCompanyPerVersion` field easily. I want to do the same using AIQL but I'm not able to do this. Here's a query that I am tried -

```
customEvents
| summarize count() by name, application_Version
| project name, application_Version, count_
| summarize x = count(count_) by application_Version
| where x = count_
```

Basically I want to get the most common Name per application_Version. How can I do this?

Comment: For people not that advanced in SQL =) Can you please elaborate on what you'd like to achieve? Pick the top Name (based on count) for each application_Version and print "application_Version, name"?

Comment: @ZakiMa yes that's exactly I wanted to say (in the last statement of my question, I tried to say so). =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[arg_max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction) should do the trick:

```
customEvents
| summarize count() by Name, application_Version
| summarize arg_max(count_, Name) by application_Version
| order by application_Version 
| project application_Version, Name=max_count__Name
```

Comment: This gets me my intended results. But did you really had to order the intermediate results?

Comment: No, you can safely remove intermediate "order by". Not needed.

Comment: Updated & removed extra "order by"

Comment: function is arg_max now

Comment: Thank you! Updated both the name of a function and a link.